# What's the musical term for when the third and/or fourth measure of a phrase in a children's song is exclaimed instead of sung?

Tags: voice

I have noticed this phenomenon with several of my child's toys and children's cartoons where they sing. Basically, on the third and/or fourth measure of some phrases, the singer of the song will exclaim or say the lyrics rather than sing them. For example, in the alphabet song, "L-M-N-O-P!" is exclaimed with excitement as opposed to being sung like the letters preceding it. Is anyone familiar with this, and is there a name for it?

Comment: It’s probably the same as the non-musical term: speaking

Comment: Not sure what it's called, but it's represented on the stave with xxxs rather than dots.

Comment: I've seen notation "spoken", with xxx's rather than dots, as @Tim commented.

Comment: FWIW, I've never heard "L-M-N-O-P" exclaimed, only sung. The question might benefit from additional examples.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it happens.

No, there's no special name for it, apart from a simple description.

Answer (score -4):

As part of a phrase, I think *climax* is a fine term to use.

Also, for the big, loud rendition of a final verse, you might call it the *grande finale*. You didn't ask that, but actually I though that was your question until I re-read it more carefully.

Comment: I have a really bad feeling that "climax" and "grande finale" (can) apply to those last, louder measures regardless of whether they are shouted/said or sung. I think the OP wants what to call shouted/said versions only.